# Searching an array of items in NetSuite using SuiteScript 2

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am attempting to write a suitescript search that allows me to pass an array of identifiers to a particular field in Netsuite and return the results. I have tried 'ANYOF', 'ALLOF' and "WITHIN' but I keep getting errors

Here is my code so far:

```
    if(params.type=='sku'){
        var filter_name = 'itemid';
    }else{
        var filter_name = 'upccode';
    }


    var filters = [
       search.createFilter({
            name: filter_name,
            operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
            values: ['HERHR5201','HERHR5202','HERHR5203']
       }),
    ];

    var s = search.create({
        'type': record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, 
      'filters':filters,

    }).run();
    s = s.getRange(0,100);

    return JSON.stringify(s);
```

Does anyone know the right sequence to create a multiple search of itemid's? Also, for a bonus, is there a way to have the resultset return the columns I need verses just the ideas? Do I need to createColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `ANYOF`, `ALLOF`, etc. when filtering a search on a text field. You'll need to create a filter expression with ORs to search on multiple values.

I would do this:

```
if(params.type=='sku'){
    var filter_name = 'itemid';
}else{
    var filter_name = 'upccode';
}

var filters = [
    [filter_name, 'is', 'HERHR5201'], 'OR',
    [filter_name, 'is', 'HERHR5202'], 'OR',
    [filter_name, 'is', 'HERHR5203']
];

var s = search.create({
    'type': record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, 
    'filters':filters
}).run();
```

As far as returning specific columns from your search, you'll need to use search.createColumn(), as you point out. So it'd be something like:

```
//Previous code...
var s = search.create({
    'type': record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM, 
    'filters':filters,
    'columns': [search.createColumn({name: 'internalid'}),
                search.createColumn({name: 'upccode'}),
                search.createColumn({name: 'itemid'})
                /*Other columns as needed*/]
}).run();
```

Answer (score 2):

The provided answer is correct, however based on your example code provided I am assuming that the search needs to be created somewhat dynamically. Meaning the 'array of identifiers' you mention will not always be the same, nor will they always be the same length. In order to create a search that is completely dynamic based on incoming 'array of identifiers' you would need to get pretty creative. In the below solution I am assuming the function parameter 'params' is an object with a 'type' property, and an arrIn (array of strings) property. The search below uses the formula function 'DECODE', a description of which can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm).

```
function execute(params) {
    var filter_name;
    var itemSearchObj;
    var stringArr = '';
    var arrIn = params.arrIn;
    var i;
    var count;

    // create search filter type
    filter_name = params.type === 'sku' ? 'itemid' : 'upccode';

    // create stringArr using incoming arrIn
    for (i = 0; arrIn && arrIn.length > i; i += 1) {
        stringArr += i > 0 ? ", '" + arrIn[i] + "', 'true'" : "'" + arrIn[i] + "', 'true'";
    }
    if (arrIn.length > 0) {
        itemSearchObj = nsSearch.create({
            type: 'item',
            filters: [
                ["formulatext: DECODE({" + filter_name + "}," + stringArr + ")", "is", 'true']
            ],
            columns: [
                'itemid', // dont need to get fancy here, just put the internal id of whichever fields you want in the columns
                'description'
            ]
        });
        count = itemSearchObj.runPaged().count;
        itemSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
            // Do things for each result
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I am looking to do. One more question. Does anyone know how to add in a join to get the quantity on hand for the Inventory Item record?

Comment: @WallyKolcz I recommend building the Search in the UI to get the results you want to see first. Once you have that, get the chrome extension called NetSuite: Search Export. This extension adds a new button to the saved search edit screen that will pop out and display the search you built in code version. It shows both SS 1.0 and SS 2.0 versions of the search.

Comment: Can I use decode to turn a string into part of the filter array? I added the extension and it created a SS2 script but I still need a way to add the filtering of the array of items passed to the script via params. I tried to use the DECODE function to take the string and have it used in the filters but I am getting a DECODE is not a function error from NS. Also, when using run().each(function(result){}), what is being returned and how do I capture something like internalId? Do I have to create a new array from each result and then send it back stringified? I do miss console.log() lol

Comment: For example (with Decode) I tried this and I get the error: error message:org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "DECODE" is not defined.

  filters: [
            DECODE([[filter_name,"is","847864149472"],"OR",[filter_name,"is","847864149489"],"OR",[filter_name,"is","847864149496"]]), 
            "AND", 
            ["inventorylocation.internalidnumber","equalto","1"], 
            "AND", 
            ["pricing.pricelevel","anyof","5"], 
            "AND", 
            ["pricing.currency","anyof","1"]
         ],

Comment: You need to pass in the search function as a string exactly the way I show in the above answer. DECODE is not a Javascript or SUITEscript function at all, its a SQL query function and therefore must be passed in as a string. On top of that, the data inside the string must be formatted as a string properly, which is done directly above the search.create(). In your last comment please look at the 'filters' you passed in to the search compared to what was provided as an example. They are not at all the same. As for what search.run().each() does, that you should already know, its explained in help

Comment: This is how you would build the string for 'stringArr':

var arrIn = ['847864149472', '847864149489', '847864149496'];
for (i = 0; arrIn && arrIn.length > i; i += 1) {
            stringArr += i > 0 ? ", '" + arrIn[i] + "', 'true'" : "'" + arrIn[i] + "', 'true'";
        }

Comment: and this is what your filters would look like
filters: [
                    ['formulatext: DECODE({' + filter_name + '},' + stringArr + ')', 'is', 'true'],
                    'AND',
                    ['inventorylocation.internalidnumber', 'equalto', '1'],
                    'AND',
                    ['pricing.pricelevel', 'anyof', '5'],
                    'AND',
                    ['pricing.currency', 'anyof', '1']
                ],

Comment: Thanks @Todd! I updated the script and the filter. I checked to see if there string being produced after passing in 3 ids from my API call and I get this as the result: 'HERHR5701', 'true', 'HERHR5702', 'true', 'HERHR5703', 'true', 'HERHR5704', 'true' - Good so far(?).

Comment: I updated my filter to look like this: filters: [["formulatext: DECODE({" + filter_name + "}," + stringArr + ")", "is", 'true'], 'AND', ['inventorylocation.internalidnumber', 'equalto', '1'], 'AND', ['pricing.pricelevel', 'anyof', '5'], 'AND', ['pricing.currency', 'anyof', '1']],

And I am getting "type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_EXPR_TYPE","message":"Malformed search filter expression, first two elements must be strings." right at the start of the itemSearchObj = search.create({

Comment: @WallyKolcz the stringArr should look just like this when its completed: "'HERHR5701', 'true', 'HERHR5702', 'true', 'HERHR5703', 'true', 'HERHR5704', 'true'". You should see that its a string that contains quoted strings, that is what makes building it a little tricky.

Comment: I added a double quote before and after the string generation to create : "'HERHR5701', 'true', 'HERHR5702', 'true', 'HERHR5703', 'true', 'HERHR5704', 'true'" but when I try to run it I am still getting: error message:{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_INVALID‌​_SRCH_FILTER_EXPR_TY‌​PE","message":"Malfo‌​rmed search filter expression, first two elements must be strings."... Can you email me at wally(at)resultco.com so I can send you the script I have and offer to pay to get this working so I can see how it supposed to look?

Answer (score 0):

I found this quite a bit of a curveball as I was overthinking it. The search requires an array:

```
results = search.create({
   type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
   filters: [],
   columns: [ search.createColumn({ name: "internalid", sort: search.Sort.ASC }) ]
})
```

This filter array consists of a search term array and logical operators (AND, OR).

```
['fieldid', 'is', yourValue], // search term array
'AND' // logical operator
```

So you can create your own filter array, by pushing in the search terms and logical operators as required.

For example if you want to return the internal id for customer emails in an array:

```
let email = ['abc@test.com', 'def@test.com'];
let myFilter = createFilter(email);

function createFilter(email){
  let filter = [];
  email.forEach((result, index) => {
    if(index > 0)
      filter.push('OR'); // Logical Operator
    
    filter.push(['email', 'is', result]);
  });
  return filter;
}
```

Variable myFilter will now equal:

```
[ ['email', 'is', 'abc@test.com'], 'OR', ['email', 'is', 'def@test.com'] ]
```

And can be directly referenced as the filter in the search.

```
let results = search.create({
   type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
   filters: myFilter,
   columns: [ search.createColumn({ name: "internalid", sort: search.Sort.ASC }) ]
})
```